# Blank White Screen on Startup but fine in preview iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

My files are as such

main.Storyboard

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var pctA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pctF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pctM: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxM: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsM: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var creditNum: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbTFone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbTFtwo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbTFthree: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbTFfour: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbImgOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbImgTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbImgThree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bbImageFour: UIImageView!


class course {

    var percentA:Int
    var percentF:Int
    var percentM:Int
    var maxAssignment:Int
    var maxFinal:Int
    var maxMidterm:Int
    var pointsA:Int
    var pointsF:Int
    var pointsM:Int
    var numofCredits:Int
    var courseName:String


    init (courseName: String, numofCredits: Int, pointsM: Int, pointsF: Int, pointsA: Int, maxMidterm: Int, maxFinal: Int, maxAssignment: Int, percentA: Int, percentF: Int, percentM: Int) {

        self.courseName = courseName
        self.numofCredits = numofCredits
        self.pointsM = pointsM
        self.pointsF = pointsF
        self.pointsA = pointsA
        self.maxMidterm = maxMidterm
        self.maxFinal = maxFinal
        self.maxAssignment = maxAssignment
        self.percentA = percentA
        self.percentF = percentF
        self.percentM = percentM

    }

}



@IBAction func addCourse(sender: AnyObject) {

    let newCourse = course(courseName: courseTitle.text!, numofCredits: Int(creditNum.text!)!, pointsM: Int(creditNum.text!)!, pointsF: Int(creditNum.text!)!, pointsA: Int(creditNum.text!)!, maxMidterm: Int(creditNum.text!)!, maxFinal: Int(creditNum.text!)!, maxAssignment: Int(creditNum.text!)!, percentA: Int(creditNum.text!)!, percentF: Int(creditNum.text!)!, percentM: Int(creditNum.text!)! )


    var courseArray = [newCourse]

    var assignmentPts = ((newCourse.pointsA)/(newCourse.maxAssignment) * newCourse.percentA)

    var midtermPts = ((newCourse.pointsA)/(newCourse.maxAssignment) * newCourse.percentA)

    var finalPts = ((newCourse.pointsA)/(newCourse.maxAssignment) * newCourse.percentA)

    var totalPts = assignmentPts + midtermPts + finalPts



    func appendtoBB() {



        for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {

        if bbTFone == nil {

            self.bbTFone.text = courseArray[0].courseName

        } else if (bbTFtwo == nil) {

            self.bbTFtwo.text = courseArray[1].courseName

        } else if (bbTFthree == nil) {

            self.bbTFthree.text = courseArray[2].courseName

        } else {

            self.bbTFfour.text = courseArray[3].courseName

        }

        }


    }



    func courseGrade() {



        if totalPts > 90 {

            bbImgOne.image = UIImage(named: "grade_a")

        } else if totalPts > 80 {

            bbImgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "grade_b")

        } else if totalPts > 70 {

            bbImgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "grade_c")

        } else if totalPts > 60 {

            bbImgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "grade_d")

        } else {

            bbImgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "grade_f")

        }


    }


    appendtoBB()
    courseGrade()


}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}




}
```

When I simulate my application, I end up having a blank white screen on startup vs. being in the preview and it showing my mainStoryboard as the startup screen. I've already define Launch Screen File Base Name as : main and file storyboard file base name as : main.  Also, when the app runs, I generate a warning that says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a ViewController set as initial ViewController in storyboard?

Comment: Yes it's set to initial ViewController

Comment: Check your connections to your outlets to make sure they are all still correct.  If you changed a name you will have remove that connection. Use assistant editor in combination with connections property view.

Comment: Is anything being outputted in the console when you get the SIGABRT?